# How to change html part of a tag with jquery?

Tags: jquery, html, text, replace

I have ,

```
`<span class="icon">&#9658;</span>`
```

in Jquery I did,

```
$(this).html('&#9660;');
```

and tried `$(this).replaceWith('&#9660;');` too.

but it displays '`&#9660;`' instead of converting it to a html icon like ▼.

thanks

Comment: Can you post your entire function where this code came from?

Answer (score 3):

This works just fine: `$("span.icon").html('&#9660;');`

Answer (score 1):

Why not just hardcode the unicode literal?

```
$('<span>').text('▼').appendTo('body')
```

You have to make sure you're serving the js file as UTF-8 though.

Edit: `.html()` should also work fine..

```
$('<span>').html('&#9660;').appendTo('body')
```

Make sure the `this` reference is pointing to the correct object, you can do var foo = this; before switching function scope.

Answer (score 0):

What is `this` referring to? I think you might not be the `span` tag. Here's a working example.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<html>
<head>
    <title>Test</title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
        $('span.icon').html('&#9660;');
    });
    </script>
</head>
<body>

<span class="icon">&#9658;</span>

</body>
</html>
```